# servlet don't respond to remote requests

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, windows-firewall, servlet-listeners

on windows 10 machine.

**ISSUE:** servlet works on private ip over 8080 port, but i can't access it remotely.

**SOLUTIONS I TRIED:**

- open port 8080(port I use on connectors) on firewall | turn off firewall (done)
- disable all anti-viruses (done)
- tried once public ip on connector `address`, Engine `defaultHost`, Host `name` (and combination of all of them), and the same with private ip!(done)

I skimmed tomcat/config documentations nothing helpful!

Comment: Is your ISP blocking the port?

Comment: should i contact them or there is other way to find out?

Comment: You should be able to just try and telnet into another server on port 8080 and if it cannot connect than your ISP is blocking the port but otherwise your issue lies elsewhere. You should be able to find a server on the internet that runs on 8080

Comment: ok, thanx i will try.

Comment: i tried that site http://portquiz.net:8080/ on port 8080. it works fine.

Comment: What is the error message in the browser?